# Set text to edittext (exception)

Tags: java, android, xml, android-edittext

I have :

```
 nameET=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
 nameET.setText("kkkk");
```

inside Oncreat() function, the code give exception as below:
[image]

Comment: you have a NullPointerException

Comment: probably `nameET` is null so make sure you are calling setContentView before accessing Views using right layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `NullPointerException` So there may be various reason for that.

- First check that you have declare your activity in the `manifest.xml`
- Second check the name of the `edittext` in your layout is it same you as `editText1`.
- Third are you calling `setContentView(R.layout.your layout where you declare your edittext);` in `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method of the activity.

If all the above you checked is fine then just clean your project and run. This will work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check your xml layout and make sure `editText1` is there.

Answer (score 0):

Two Quick Checks,

- Did you declare the activity in `manifest.xml`
- Are you using the same name `editText1` as specified in xml and is it `EditText` Defined

Answer (score 0):

`setContentView` is missing. Please check this in your code

Answer (score 0):

```
          View inflatedView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_sliding, null);

        nameET=(EditText)inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                 nameET.setText("kkkk");
```

===============================================

use the activity which contain R.id.editText1 instead of activity_sliding